# Not able to run scenario outline feature with Cucumber

Tags: junit, cucumber

I'm Running Cucumber feature file with Scenario outline feature and Examples keyword , while runnin the testing getting **junit cucumber internalizing error**
please help me out

```
**Scenario Outline: Launch and Login CRM Application with simple data driven with examples**
Given user is already on Login Page 
When title of login page is Free CRM
Then I should login into the application with "<UserName>" as username and "<PassWord>" as password
And close the applciation
Examples:
     |UserName             |PassWord |
     |parthipan**@gmail.com|*****|
```

Comment: Please review the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask pages. If you don't include the full error, stack trace and other relevant information it becomes very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the `*` characters aren't part of the styling for this site (for the Scenario Outline line), I would say that the reason it in't finding the test is due to that.

The `*` characters will be fine for just the description (after the `Scenario Outline:`)

If it isn't due to this, then we'll need more information (perhaps a dump of the stack trace) to be able to help